# Force Window Size Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I don't find how to force the window **size** with the kivy language. (ex: 800x600p)

Can you help me ?

Thanks for reading.

PITO2901

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KV language does not have the ability to configure window settings, but it can be done easily in your 'main.py' file by using the `Config` object from `kivy.config`. Just make sure to put any configuration you do *before* your other imports. Otherwise, they won't work.

```
# configuration
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width',  800)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 600)

# other imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Set kivy.core.window.Window.size to (800, 600).

You can't set it directly in kv, but you could bind it to a button or similar. You would also need to import the Window to kv, using the `#:import` statement explained in the doc.

Comment: Thanks ! But I'm french and i don't understand all the kivy doc, so  can you give me a way to write a part of code to use this function please ? (just a simple one)

Comment: `from kivy.core.window import Window; Window.size = (800, 600)`.