# How do I re-set Kivy config?

Tags: python, macos, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window(800, 500)
```

was working. Then I ported to a new system to continue testing (literally, just a new user profile on the same node) and it stopped working.

I stumbled across this:

```
from kivy import config

fig = config.Config

fig.set('kivy', 'desktop',     '1')
fig.set('graphics', 'custom_titlebar',     '1')
fig.set('graphics', 'borderles',           '1')
fig.set('graphics', 'custom_titlebar',     '1')
fig.set('graphics', 'fullscreen',          '0')
fig.set('graphics', 'resizable',           '1')
# fig.set('graphics', 'width',            '800')
# fig.set('graphics', 'height',           '400')
fig.set('graphics', 'minimum_width',     '400')
fig.set('graphics', 'minimum_height',    '200')
fig.set('graphics', 'maxfps',             '60')
fig.set('graphics', 'always_on_top',      '1' )
fig.set('graphics', 'allow_screensaver',  '1' )
fig.set('graphics', 'maxfps',             '60')
fig.set('graphics', 'allow_screensaver',  '1' )

print(fig.write()) # Output: True
fig.write()
```

I also used `fig.setdefault(as_above)` and now all my kivy configs are.

It's not resizing like normal, going into fullscreen is to no avail either.

How do I reset the config to the original kivy formula?

I tried to determine the size of the `app.window`.

I expected the config to print to a file. Maybe I was reading the code wrong when I was crawling through the packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Window Size Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234386/force-window-size-kivy)

Comment: Search *[python] [kivy] window size* returns multiple hits on SO alone. Using `.core.`didn't seem like the norm. Is anyone of these helping? It looks like you should provide version information for what's running on that node, as well.

Comment: Maybe you did not grasp the message? Let me present the code so you get a better picture?

Comment: If you believe some more code is useful to clarify your question, then by all means add it -though please inside your original post, not in the answers section.
First of all you could explicit what you mean by "WAS WORKING" (then which unexpected behaviour or which error traceback?) Idem for the code snippet you "stumbled across". You list a number of attempts and that is all right, but then do not make it clear what the issue(s) is with each of them. Surely it is not the same response every time?